# Creating calendar event without recurrence end date fails

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

Creating calendar event without Recurrence.Range.End date fails with the following message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorRecurrenceEndDateTooBig",
         "message": "Recurrence end date can not exceed Sep 1, 4500 00:00:00."
    }
}
```

I tried the request with both this date set to UTC zero date and removing the parameter at all. This issue can be related to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240016/recurrence-range-startdate-enddate-contain-timezone-offset)

Example requests:

1) Without Recurrence.Range.End:

```
{
    "Subject": "test event",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "sadsad"
    },
    "Start": "2015-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    "End": "2015-05-27T00:30:00.000Z",
    "Attendees": [],
    "Recurrence": {
        "Pattern": {
            "DayOfMonth": 0,
            "Month": 0,
            "Type": "Daily",
            "Interval": 3,
            "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday"
        },
        "Range": {
            "NumberOfOccurrences": 0,
            "Type": "NoEnd"
        }
    }
}
```

2) With Recurrence.Range.Start:

```
    {
    "Subject": "No title",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "sadsad"
    },
    "Start": "2015-05-27T03:30:00.000Z",
    "End": "2015-05-27T04:00:00.000Z",
    "Attendees": [],
    "Recurrence": {
        "Pattern": {
            "DayOfMonth": 0,
            "Month": 0,
            "Type": "Daily",
            "Interval": 3,
            "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday"
        },
        "Range": {
            //Actually this is the way this field comes when reading such 
            //events from the REST API, which is a bit strange:
            "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "NumberOfOccurrences": 0,
            "Type": "NoEnd"
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone check if I'm missing something or this is an issue (bug)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `StartDate` field in the `Range`.

```
"Range": {
    "StartDate": "2015-05-27T00:00:00Z",
    "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "NumberOfOccurrences": 0,
    "Type": "NoEnd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how exactly I missed this.